# Create table and insert values from different datatypes

Tags: sql

**Code:**

```
create table "tab1" ("c1" varchar(max));
create table "tab2" ("c3" integer);
insert into tab1 values(N'asd'), (N'qweqwe');
insert into tab2 values(123), (345);
select
c_newname as myname
from
(
select "c1" as c_newname from "tab1"
union all
select cast("c3"  as varchar(max)) from "tab2"
) as T_UNI;
```

How to create new table("tab3") and insert values from(tab1),(tab2) into table("tab3"). Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *looks* like you're using SQL Server, so you can use *into*

```
select c_newname as myname
into tab3
from...
```